# Verification of Proof of a Bijection from A to B

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Problem:  For $ a,b \in \textbf{R}$ with $ a < b$, prove an explicit bijection of $ A = \{ x : a < x < b \} $ onto $ B = \{ y : 0 < y < 1\} $.

My attempt:  We consider $ f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x-a}{b-a} $.

Proof that $ f$ is injective:  Suppose $ f(i) = f(j) $ where $ i,j\in\textbf{R} $.  Then $ \displaystyle \frac{i-a}{b-a} = \frac{j-a}{b-a} $.  If we multiply both sides by $ b-a $ and then add $ a$ to both sides we obtain $ i=j $.  Thus $ f $ is injective.

Proof that $ f $ is surjective over $ \textbf{R} $:  Take some $ m \in \textbf{R} $.  Let $ k = (b-a)m+a $.  Then

$ f(k)= \displaystyle \frac{k-a}{b-a} = \frac{(b-a)m+a-a}{b-a} = \frac{(b-a)m}{b-a}=m $.

Having established that $ f$ is surjective over $ \textbf{R} $, we now must prove that if $ 0 < m < 1 $, then $ a < k < b $.

Given that $ f $ is injective, we have that $ k = (b-a)m+a $ is the unique solution for $f(k)= m $.  Noting that $ b>a $ means $ (b-a)>0 $, it follows if we have two values $ m_1, m_2 $ in $ B $ such that $ m_1 < m_2 $, then we can say that $ k_1,k_2 $ defined by $ f(k_1)=m_1 $ and $ f(k_2)=m_2 $ will have the property that $ k_1 < k_2 $.  Thus it is sufficient to show that $ k_1 =a$ and $ k_2=b $ to show that $ k_i $, defined by $ f(k_i) = m_i  $ where $  m_1 < m_i <m_2  $, will satisfy that $a <  k_i < b $, thus proving that $ A $ maps onto $ B $.

Suppose $ m_1 = 0 $.  Then $ k_1 = (b-a)*0 + a = a $.  Allow that $ m_2 = 1 $.  Then $ k_2 = (b-a)*1 + a = b $.  Thus $ f $ maps $ A$ onto $ B $.  So $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

I'm not sure whether or not my proof for the interval is valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this other idea? You can get from $(a,b)$ to $(0,1)$, using a composition of two operations, each of which is a bijection: 1)scaling the length of any one of the intervals, so that the lengths are equal , and 2) Translating,i.e., or moving the scled interval so that it overlaps the other interval.Then you have a composition of two bijections, which is a bijection.

Comment: Are there specific theorems for these transformations, or would these instead be done as lemmas specific to this proof?

Comment: @Dargatz: I think the lemmas showing this should be relatively straightforward: the map $x\rightarrow x/(b-a)$ is a bijection, because it has the inverse $(b-a)/x$; similar for the scaling map.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(a)=0$, $f(b)=1$, $f'(x)=1/(b-a)>0$.

Comment: Does this mean I should hold off on proofs of this nature until i've some experience with doing proofs that involve calculus?

I know calculus, but i've never done proofs with it.

Comment: It's always sometimes the first time.